# Bing Maps - Auto update location binding of pushpins

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, location, bing-maps

I'm using the Bing Maps control to display a series of custom pushpins, representing objects which are constantly moving around and changing state.

Using databinding the various properties for the objects are being updated as they should, but for some reason this doesn't apply to their locations.

I have the map bound to an ObservableCollection as such:

```
<UserControl.Resources>    
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PushpinTemplate">
        <v:CustomPushpin />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

...

```
<m:Map Name="map">
   <m:MapItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PushpinTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}" />
</m:Map>
```

...and in CustomPushpin:

```
<UserControl
...    
   m:MapLayer.Position="{Binding Location}" m:MapLayer.PositionOrigin="BottomCenter"
   mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="126" d:DesignWidth="85">
```

Like all other properties, the Location of the individual objects are implemented using INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
private Location _location;
public Location Location
{
   get { return _location; }
   set { _location = value; OnPropertyChanged("Location"); }
}
```

When the map is moving, either because of panning or zooming, the objects move, but othersize not.

I can't quite figure if I'm doing something wrong here, or if it's a problem with the Bing Maps control.

Any thought?

Comment: I got the same problem :( Any idea what possibly could be wrong, out there?

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround by Candritzky here: [Solution link with code](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bingmapssilverlightwpfcontrols/thread/683db702-6d57-4fdd-8ba5-25e37fd362eb/)

Basically you'll have to change the `ItemsPanel` to custom one that expose new `AttachedProperty`. For me it works :)

Answer (score 2):

Do not update the location, like this:

```
_pushPin.Location.Latitude = xyz...
```

instead create a new object:

```
_pushPin.Location = new Location(_location);
```

otherwise `BingMap` will somehow lose track of the update eventually

Answer (score 1):

refreshing view by

```
map.SetView(map.BoundingRectangle);
```

works

Answer (score 1):

Refreshing view didn't work for me. Instead of recreate Pushpin, the simplest solution was :

```
_pushPin.Location = null;
_pushPin.Location = _location;
```

or

```
_pushPin.Location = new Location(_location);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found something [here](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/73266/448936.aspx): it seems like there's a bug in the Bing's Map Control from Microsoft.
I even tried the suggested workaround, but it's not working for me

Comment: Yes I did consider changing the view, though not exactly in this manner, but I never tried it.

What I ended up doing was "simply" to remove and re-add the layer with the pins. I know it sounds like a very heavy operation, but judging from the result it doesn't appear to be!?

Comment: Instead I tried simply to remove the old pushpin and recreate a new pushpin with the new position. I don't know what operation is heavier...

Comment: Or better, I remove the pushpin from the collection, change the location, and re-insert the updated pushpin: the collection is observable, so the UI intercept this change and update itself accordingly.Still don't know what operation is heavier...

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wonders, my solution was to create my own class `ObjectCollection` and inherit from `ObservableCollection<Object>`. Add a method ObjectCollection.Refresh() like so:

```
public void Refresh()
{
    base.OnCollectionChanged(new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
}
```

and call this method after I'm done repopulating the collection in a loop.